# Приложения бывают только несогласованными?

Tags: приложение, синтаксис

Учитель утверждает, что приложения бывают только несогласованными, и тип связи у них -примыкание. Но я с ней не согласен. Например, в сочетании Родина-мать я "мать" охарактеризовал, как согласованное приложение, но учитель всё перечеркнула. Кто из нас прав? А как же Родиной-матерью,  о Родине-матери и т.д.? Ведь согласование – это тип подчинительной связи, главным словом в котором является существительное, а зависимое всегда стоит в том же падеже, роде и числе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложения бывают согласованные и несогласованные.

```
В согласованных приложениях форма падежа изменяется при изменении главного (определяемого) слова: студент-аспирант, студента-аспиранта.
В несогласованных приложениях форма падежа не изменяется при изменении главного слова: роман"Преступление и наказание", романом  " Преступление и наказание", и т.д.
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласованные определения согласуются с существительным в роде, числе и падеже.

Приложения согласуются с существительным в общем случае в падеже, но часто и в числе тоже: студенты-заочники, студентам-заочникам, девочки-подростки.

Однако согласование в падеже (и числе) происходит не всегда: очки-велосипед, царь-пушку, горе-охотники, с горе-охотником, на озере Байкал.

Для разных тематических групп существуют свои правила.